# Matlab: convert (i,j) matrix to (1,j) array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I got a 365x24 matrix (hours of the day x days of the year) and I'd like to convert it to a 1x8760 matrix (for all the hours of the year).

So basically, every row of the original matrix should be copy pasted after the previous row.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For any matrix, the `(:)` indexing operation concatenates the columns of the matrix to form a vector.

```
>> a = [1,2,3; 4,5,6];
>> a = a(:)
ans =
     1
     4
     2
     5
     3
     6
```

In your case, you want the rows concatenated. To achieve this, simply transpose the matrix before indexing with `(:)`. Finally, you can simply transpose it to get the row vector.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll edit the post to reflect that